# Select number of IDs in more than one table (from three tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need the count of this:

```
select distinct ID
from (
    select ID from A 
    union all
    select ID from B 
    union all
    select ID from C 
) ids
GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select ID
      from (select ID from A 
            union all
            select ID from B 
            union all
            select ID from C 
           ) ids
      group by ID
      having count(*) > 1
     ) i;
```

`SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never needed with `GROUP BY` and definitely not in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. it says Incorrect syntax near '*'.

Comment: @Lilz . . . That doesn't make sense.  `count(*)` is well supported in SQL Server and there are no other `'*'` in the code.

Comment: It only gives me this error when I use it in the query above. It usually works fine

Answer (score 0):

You just want to find the id that appear 2 more times in the A,B,C table, the SQL is below:

```
select count(1) from (
select
    id,
    count(1)
from
    (
    select ID from A 
    union all
    select ID from B 
    union all
    select ID from C 
   ) 
group by id having(count(1)>1)
) tmp
```